# How to handle radio Buttons with react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm building a React Component. This is a form, with a radio button, which can only be set to True and then no longer set back to false. I would like to be able to turn it on and off. And because worth read out.
What could the corresponding code look like?
At the moment I have that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form extends Component {
art = {
selected: "uppper"
}
 onChange() {
console.log("Click")
 }
render() {
 return (
  <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" value="option1"
        onClick={this.onChange} />
        option1
      </label>
    </div>  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   );
  }
 } 
export default Form;
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, please try my solution below. That should provide you some insight on all the tools you need to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

while being consistent with using a class-component, your code would look something like this:

```
class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: false
  };
  onChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      selected: !this.state.selected
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="option1"
              onClick={this.onChange}
              checked={this.state.selected}
            />
            option1
          </label>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default Form;
```

Essentially what you need are 3 things.

1. A Boolean value in your state to keep track of the button was
   clicked (true or false).
2. Give the input a checked property which matches the value of the
   selected state.
3. Update the `onChange` handler to toggle the state value. Also ensure
   that the `onChange` handler is bound to the execution context by using
   an arrow function or binding the this keyword.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-borg-gwl2q

Comment: thanks but i geht this error: index.js:1375 Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

Comment: and if i edit onClick to onChange the error is away. but i cant switch the radio button ...
any ideas?

Comment: @DennisSchaffer I think its safe to disregard that error. The type of functionality that you're looking for is only available via an onClick handler. Otherwise, you will not be able to toggle the selected state. Rest assured, this error message has no affect on your feature as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => { 
  const [radioState, setRadioState] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = () => { 
    setRadioState(!radioState)
  }

  return (
    <input type="radio" checked={radioState} onClick={handleChange}/>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bmwj5a).